# Google Maps Directions API: Computes whether the given point lies on route

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Computes whether the given point lies on the path, here is what I have tried so far:

```
const googleMapsClient  = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: 'KEY'
});

googleMapsClient.directions({
    origin: 'Bangalore, Karnataka',
    destination: 'Mumbai, Maharathra',
    mode: "driving",
}, function(err, response) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(response);
    }
console.error("ERR", err);
})
```

This API returning route details.
Is there a way by which I can get the same feature of `isLocationOnPath`(a method in Android SDK) function in  Google Node.JS Client.

Comment: I'm afraid the only way is to get the source code and implement the function in node.js (see https://github.com/jefersondeoliveira/android-hackathon/blob/master/google-maps-utils/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java)

Answer (score 0):

[Node.js Client for Google Maps Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js) doesn't have any geometry functions, but as an alternative you can use [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org) and [mapbox/polyline](https://github.com/mapbox/polyline) the following way

```
googleMapsClient.directions({
    origin: 'Bangalore, Karnataka',
    destination: 'Mumbai, Maharathra',
    mode: "driving",
})
.asPromise()
.then((response) => {
    let points = []
    response.json.routes[0].legs[0].steps.forEach( (step) => {
        polyline.decode(step.polyline.points).forEach( (point) => {
            points.push([point[1], point[0]])
        })
    })
    let linestring = turf.lineString(points)
    let snapped = turf.nearestPointOnLine(linestring, turf.point([77.59464, 12.9726]))
    console.log(snapped.properties.dist)
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

So if snapped.properties.dist <= some value, than it means the point belongs to the route with the given tolerance.